# How to disable background execution of Adobe AIR app on Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a couple of Adobe AIR apps for Android.
An issue I encounter is that execution of the app continues when the app is in the background, for instance when the user presses the device's home button.
The framerate drops to about 2 fps, but audio and timers just continue.

I need the app/script execution to pause when not activated. I don't want timers, audio, timelines etc to continue. Pausing/resuming them all myself on Event.DEACTIVATE/Event.ACTIVATE is not really feasible, due to the complexity and structure of the apps.

I have tried explicitly setting 'NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = false', with no effect.
There is nothing in my manifest xml that does anything with background execution.

I am using Adobe AIR 16.0.
I have tested on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014, Samsung Galaxy S4, which both run Android 4.4+

On stackoverflow I see a number of questions asking the opposite, so this behaviour seems odd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can monitore these events: `Event.ACTIVATE` and `Event.DEACTIVATE` to know when the application is activated or deactivated (background)

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, function(event:Event):void
{
    // activated    
});

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, function(event:Event):void
{
    // deactivated
});
```

Comment: I have implemented those event listeners already. The point is, I am looking for a way to pause the app when deactivated. These events are of course useful, but execution of the app just continues as before.

Comment: example, I have an app with sound and lots of 3D objects, when the Event.DEACTIVATE is triggered, I just stop the sound and the 3D render (so, the execution of the app is not as before), and when the Event.ACTIVATE is triggered I play the sound and the 3D render.

Comment: Ok, those cases are easy to do manually, but my apps have a complex structure with a lot of timed events etc. I am looking for an overall / topdown way of completely pausing app execution during the inactive period.

Comment: You have to structure your app in such a way that you **can** pause it completely. In games this is usually a central place where you start/stop a heartbeat timer (I like a simple `enterFrame` event handler). If you've scattered various timers all over the place without any central hooks, then yes, it's not going to be easy. There's no way to pause the runtime in a normal environment.

Comment: @Aaron is totally right! You should be able to start/stop any scope at any time. Have timers and loops running in background will break the reason why they are running and also consume resources from the user device